# SQL case - else condition visited even when other condition is true

Tags: sql, case

Here is my query -

```
Select distinct P1.PastaName, P1.PastaColor,
CASE
    When
  S1.SauceID = P1.PastaID
THEN S1.SauceType
ELSE NULL
END AS PastaCombo
From Pasta P1, Sauce S1
```

Regardless of whether or not the Pasta ID and Sauce ID match up, I expect only one row per Pasta to be returned for each pasta. However, that is not the case. When Pasta ID and Sauce ID do not match up, there is only one row for the pasta that is returned with the PastaCombo value being null. However, if Pasta ID and Sauce ID do match up, there are two rows for the Pasta that are returned - one that says "Pasta Combo" and one that says "null".

Why is that? How can I reduce the result to one row when there is a match and just have "Pasta Combo" be returned and not null as well?

According to this - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43352/does-sql-server-case-statement-evaluate-all-conditions-or-exit-on-first-true-con - the else condition is only visited if there is no true condition. But there is a true condition on my end, so I am not sure why the else condition is being visited.

this is the result I want

```
PastaName           PastaColor       SauceType
_________           __________       __________

Ravioli              Brown           Tomato
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data, the current result and the wanted result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: you tagged it as mysql and refer to a link that about sql server, they are different rsms and so could not react the same way. Please add a [mre] so that we can understand your prolem better

Comment: The select list case expression does not filter. Use JOIN ... ON instead.

Comment: I already tried using join @jarlh. I also updated my post with an example of what I want the result to be like. This was the join I did: "Select distinct P1.PastaName, P1.PastaColor from Pasta P1
JOIN
(SELECT S1.SauceType from Sauce S1) as Italian". 

Both Pasta and Sauce have an ID attribute that is common between them. However, if I use ON to set them equal to each other, I get an error. With the current join statement, the SauceType is not being displayed. and yes, I do want null to be displayed if there is not a match.

Comment: Please provide sample data which will give a clear picture.

Comment: @ilikepizzayum . . . I don't know what "redacted" post is supposed to mean.  As the OP you can delete the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
From Pasta P1, Sauce S1
```

what you actually do is a `CROSS` join of the 2 tables, meaning the Cartesian product of the rows.
I suspect that what you want is a `LEFT` join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  P1.PastaName, P1.PastaColor,
  CASE WHEN S1.SauceID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Pasta Combo' END AS PastaCombo
FROM Pasta P1 LEFT JOIN Sauce S1
ON S1.SauceID = P1.PastaID
```

or use `EXISTS` without a join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  P1.PastaName, P1.PastaColor,
  CASE WHEN (EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM Sauce S1 WHERE S1.SauceID = P1.PastaID) THEN 'Pasta Combo' END AS PastaCombo
FROM Pasta P1
```